# Add Dates in a loop netsuite scripting

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to print dates by adding more days to them by using nlapiAddDays() in a loop

```
var startdate = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol_startdt',i+1);
var enddate = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol_enddt',i+1);

var stringtodate1 = nlapiStringToDate(startdate);
var stringtodate2 = nlapiStringToDate(enddate);

//BELOW FORMULA I USED TO GET NUMBER OF MONTHS BETWEEN TWO DATES
var diff =(stringtodate2.getTime() - stringtodate1.getTime()) / 1000;
var diffMonths = Math.ceil(diff / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4)-1);

if(diffMonths > 1)
{
  for(i=0; i <= diffMonths; i++)
  { var AddDays = 30;
    var days = null;    
    if(i == 0)  
    {     
       days = stringtodate1;    
    }
     else
           {
            days = nlapiAddDays(stringtodate1, AddDays);
           }
  }
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','days',days);
    AddDays++;
}
```

here,if i becomes 1,30 days are added but when i becomes 2, 60 days should get added because of AddDays++ but it is not happening.30 days are added for every loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are resetting AddDays to 30 at the top of the loop. You would need:

```
 var AddDays = 30;
 for(i=0; i <= diffMonths; i++)
 { ...
```

Comment: done that as well. this time, day is added in every loop but 1 day is added. i think i am missing something here.

Comment: `AddDays += 30`